# csh awk syntax error in if else code

Tags: awk, csh

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/csh
echo "jones 2143 78 84 77" >! student-marks
echo "Gondrol 2243 88 94 87" >> student-marks

awk '{
if ($3 >=35 && $4 >= 35 && $5 >= 35)
    print $0,"=>","Pass";
else
    print $0,"=>","Fail";
}' student-marks
```

which I copied directly from the URL 
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements/

as an example to learn how to use if else logic with awk. Unfortunately I keep getting the error Unmatched '
Any advice?

Comment: See the answers as below. Note that you could make your `awk` a little more awkish: `awk '$3 >=35 && $4 >= 35 && $5 >= 35 { print $0,"=>","Pass"; next } { print $0,"=>","Fail" }' file`. Guilty by default.

Comment: You can turn it into an awk one-liner by using the ternary operator: `awk '{print $0, "=>", ($3 >=35 && $4 >= 35 && $5 >= 35) ? "Pass" : "Fail"}' student-marks`

Answer (score 2):

Change `csh` to `sh` or `bash`.

```
#!/bin/sh
...
```

Csh doesn't handle the multi-line quoted string in the same way that Posix shells do.

Answer (score 2):

[DigitalRoss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140740/digitalross) is correct that csh handles multi-line quoted strings differently than POSIX shells, and that using `sh` or `bash` is likely to be easier.  `csh` is generally considered to be a poor choice for scripting (though some people prefer it, particularly in its `tcsh` variant, for interactive use).

See ["Csh Programming Considered Harmful"](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) for discussion of the problems with using `csh` for scripting.

But it is possible to do what you want using csh. You just need to add a backslash to the end of each line within the multi-line quoted string:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
echo "jones 2143 78 84 77" >! student-marks
echo "Gondrol 2243 88 94 87" >> student-marks

awk '{\
if ($3 >=35 && $4 >= 35 && $5 >= 35)\
    print $0,"=>","Pass";\
else\
    print $0,"=>","Fail";\
}' student-marks
```

Output:

```
jones 2143 78 84 77 => Pass
Gondrol 2243 88 94 87 => Pass
```

I've snuck in one more small change: adding the `-f` option to the `#!` line. This prevents `csh` from loading any resource or startup files, so the script (a) will start a little faster, and (b) will avoid accidental dependencies on your own `.cshrc` and `.login` files. (This does *not* apply to `sh` and `bash` scripts; for those shells, the `-f` option has a completely different meaning.)